# Send props between Components (no related) React-Native

Tags: react-native

I have Components directory, there is js file Timer where I have countdown Component

```
const [countdownTimer, setCountdownTimer] = useState(15);
```

This component only returns `<Text>{countdownTimer}</Text>` on screen.
I also have another component Description. I want to handle this state in my Description component to make some changes after time has changed. The components aren't related (they aren't imported in each other)

I tried to import Description in Timer to send value as a props like

```
<Description setCountdownTimer={setCountdownTimer} />
```

and with style hide it but `display: none` isn't working on Android. I also try to just hide with another method

```
{false && <Description setCountdownTimer={setCountdownTimer} />}
```

but it's also not working, I got "undefined" in console.

Answer (score 0):

For your case you should take a look at React Context: https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Comment: there isn't another way ?

Comment: If you want to share data in your react-tree at any level, you should use context as it's built-in solution in react. It fits your case because components aren't directly related.

Answer (score 0):

Hi @Danny If I understood your question correctly, you are trying to share the countDown state between two different components, and the way you try to do it may complicate you a bit, if not I suggest you use redux which is a library designed in order to manage the global states of applications, with redux you will be able to share the states of your application with several components.
You should need to create `reducers` and thanks to the `createStore` method from `**redux** you will be able to use a global state to your entire application
Here it's an example of code you can improve depending on your need :

```
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import reducer from './reducer';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
const store = createStore(reducer);

export default function App () {
  return (
    <Provider store = {store}>
      <YourMainComponent />
    </Provider>
  )
}
```

You just need to wrapp your main component with the Provider component from 'react-redux' to access to your global state and manage it as you want. See more here
https://react-redux.js.org/introduction/basic-tutorial

Comment: thanks bro for answer me but I think use new feature useContext is more interesting than Redux

Comment: You are welcom dude. useContext is more interresting u're right.